# Wait for releasing acquired locks by current HazelcastInstance when shutdown() is called

Tags: java, locking, hazelcast

Hello fellow developers,

I have serializeable object that is stored across two Hazelcast members.

Object contains some info that can be changed on only one of the Hazelcast member at the same time.

For this purpose I am using [ILock](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/ILock.html).

Everything is working fine until, Hazelcast member that acquired and holds lock for object decides to [leave](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/HazelcastInstance.html#shutdown--).

I want current Hazelcast member to wait for release its acquired and held locks before shutdown, so it can finish editing object.

Comment: Isn't this a controlled `shutdown()` of Hazelcast, while stopping your application? Can't you just manually wait until processing finishes before calling `shutdown()`?

Comment: @mdogan In this case I have to keep track of all acquired locks. I guess Hazelcast don't have method for this.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no built-in mechanism for that, as far as I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we discussed in comments (with @mdogan), there's no built-in mechanism for that.

To achieve what I wanted, I have to:

1. Store of all acquired lock keys by current Hazelcast member in `ConcurrentSkipListSet<String>`.
2. Before shutdown, loop through `ConcurrentSkipListSet<String>` check if `ILock.isLocked()`, if `true` then wait for release.
3. Shutdown current Hazelcast member.